# how to detect memory leak with debug memory graph in xcode?

Tags: xcode, react-native

[image]

for now, I'm implementing showing tons of images using section list because I have two different section. since there are a lot of images, it's too slow so I decided to test if there's memory leak somewhere using debug memory graph. but I'm having tons of memory leakage as you can see on photo.

FYI, I'm a react native developer. I want to find what causes memory leak.

Comment: Does memory really matter?

Comment: @WonixerA if you don't take this into account, you will get crash event sometimes